# Generate 10 random circles and points them in the path

Tags: java, animation, javafx

What I want: I need to generate random 10 circles, with random coordinates and points them in path. Then create a square that needs to move along that path using animation.

What is my problem: I cant create 10 random circles with random coordinates, but I created code for animation.

Here is my code, I created random curved line and square that goes along it. That curved line is just for example, because I don't know how to make circles with random coordinates and points them in path.

[Example of my code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/basics.htm#sthref23)

```
final Rectangle rectPath = new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40);
    rectPath.setArcHeight(10);
    rectPath.setArcWidth(10);
    rectPath.setFill(Color.ORANGE);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(20, 20));
    path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(380, 0, 380, 120, 200, 120));
    path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(0, 120, 0, 240, 380, 240));
    path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(420, 350, 420, 440, 10, 450));

    PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
    pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
    pathTransition.setPath(path);
    pathTransition.setNode(rectPath);
    pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
    pathTransition.setCycleCount(5);
    pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
    pathTransition.play();
    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().add(rectPath);
    root.getChildren().add(path);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 450);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Path transition demo");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: "I cant create 10 random circles with random coordinates" what exactly is stopping you? Are you facing any *specific* problem? Is it generating number in some range? Or repeat that process? Or something else? Consider adding pseudo-solution, steps which you think your application should have, and describe which step you are having problem with.

Comment: No, I want to do that with for loop, but I just dont know how, I can create them like
`Circle circle1 = new Circle();` ... and that 10 times.

Yeah, I put bad explanation.. I want to create 10 circles with for loop and put them on with random coordinates, without overlapping, and then I want to points them in path, something like connect them with line, and on that line I will add one square that will goes on it.

Comment: Consider creating class like `MyCircle` which will store `x,y,r`. Then add to it method which will check if it overlaps other cycle like `boolean overlaps(MyCycle otherCycle){ return distanceFromCenters(this, otherCycle)<this.r+otherCycle.r;}`. Now just loop until you have 10 circles, in each iteration create one circle, add it to some list, but only after confirming that it doesn't overlap other circles already stored in list. If it overlaps even one, generate another circle until you can add it to list. Repeat 10 times.

Comment: Looks like you are a first time user, please consider the following tips: While asking a question try to elaborate the efforts you put for the issue. People will try to respond once they notice your efforts. Also try to make your question as narrow & specific as possible. Most users will not show interest in broad questions. In your question we cannot see any efforts from you. Even the code you pasted is almost the code from the doc. Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and point out where the exact issue you are facing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How to create 10 random points for PathTransition*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55007155/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check my comment regarding the question. It is not something very complex. It is all about learning the concepts and putting them together. Assuming that you might be a beginner, please find the below example for your requirement.

```
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RandomPathTransistionDemo extends Application {
    PathTransition pathTransition;
    Path path;

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Random Path Transistion");
        stage.show();

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        pane.setStyle("-fx-border-width:1px;-fx-border-color:black;-fx-background-color:white;");
        VBox.setVgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Button generateBtn = new Button("Generate circles");
        Button animationBtn = new Button("Start Animation");
        animationBtn.setDisable(true);

        HBox buttons = new HBox(generateBtn, animationBtn);
        buttons.setSpacing(15);
        root.getChildren().addAll(buttons, new Label("Click generate button as many times as you want !!"),pane);

        final Rectangle rectPath = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
        rectPath.setArcHeight(10);
        rectPath.setArcWidth(10);
        rectPath.setFill(Color.ORANGE);

        path = new Path();
        path.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGREEN);
        path.setStrokeWidth(2);

        generateBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            animationBtn.setDisable(false);
            if (pathTransition != null) {
                pathTransition.stop();
            }
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            path.getElements().clear();

            int width = (int) pane.getWidth() - 20;
            int height = (int) pane.getHeight() - 20;
            List<Circle> dots = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                double x = random.nextInt(width); // Get a random value of x within the pane width
                double y = random.nextInt(height);// Get a random value of y within the pane height

                // If required include your logic to see if this point is not within the range of other points.

                // Create a circle with this random point
                Circle dot = new Circle(x, y, 5, Color.RED);
                dots.add(dot);

                // Also inlcude a path element for this random point.
                path.getElements().add(i == 0 ? new MoveTo(x, y) : new LineTo(x, y));
            }

            // Add all nodes in the pane one after another to have a nice visual.
            pane.getChildren().add(path);
            pane.getChildren().addAll(dots);
            pane.getChildren().add(rectPath);

            // Move the rectangle to the start point of the path.
            rectPath.setTranslateX(dots.get(0).getCenterX() - 10); // 10 :: half of rectangle width
            rectPath.setTranslateY(dots.get(0).getCenterY() - 10); // 10 :: half of rectangle height

        });

        animationBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            pathTransition = new PathTransition();
            pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
            pathTransition.setPath(path);
            pathTransition.setNode(rectPath);
            pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
            pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
            pathTransition.play();
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```